# Is my code wrong somewhere? I don't get any email

Tags: php, email

Below is the code for my booking form email, sent from a Linux server:

```
$body = "
      <p>Hello sir,</p>
      <p>Name: <b> {$firstname}</b><br />
        Email: <b> {$email}</b><br />
        Phone: <b> {$phone}</b><br />
        Length Of Stay: <b> {$length} </b><br />
        Number in Party: <b> {$party} </b><br />
        Month : <b> {$month} </b><br />
        Day: <b> {$day} </b><br />
        Year: <b> {$year} </b><br />
        Additional information:<b> {$additional_information} </b>

      </p>
      <p>with best regards, <br /><b>My Website</b></p>
    ";


    $to = 'info@currentwebsite.com';
    $subject = 'Message';

    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: '. $email. "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$email.'' . "\r\n" ;

    if(mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers))
    {
        phpalert( 'Your request has been sent successfully!' );
    }
    else {
        phpalert( 'Sorry! could not send your request. Please try again later.' );
    }
```

Does anyone know why my mail is not coming? It shows "Your request has been sent successfully!" But I can't find any email in inbox or even in spam.

**Added**
Is there any chances of blocking mails from server?

Comment: Remove the `@` from in front of your mail function to see if any error messages are generated

Comment: Do you see the mail in your mail server logs?

Comment: if you habe a *nix enviroment, use \n as end of line in headers.

Comment: no error just says ... Your request has been sent successfully

Comment: @peko I do have \n at the end of line in headers

Comment: @sujal in your code example its "\n\r" not "\n"

Comment: Dumb question, but did You type Your email eddress correctly? Are You on localhost or on some server? If localhost maybe Your local server is not configured to send emails. If on some server maybe the `mail` function is blocked and You should use some SMTP.

Comment: @peko currently i have \r\n so u want to do me \n\r ?

Comment: @sujal no just "\n" instead of "\n\r"

Comment: @shadyyx working online... and i used test@hotmail.com

Comment: @YourCommonSense Is there any chances of blocking emails from server?

Comment: yeah, sure. it can be server itself or server's ISP or recipient's mailserver

Comment: @YourCommonSense how can we solve that problem? we can solve ourself or need to consult with server people?

Comment: To consult with server people is a first thing you had to do.

Comment: @YourCommonSense pls don't tell me header-eol doesn't matter and can't cause any problems.

Comment: @peko, RFC-822 specifies that header lines are ended with CRLF (as he has done here) - it doesn't matter what the environment is.

Comment: @PaulTomblin php documentation says:
If messages are not received, try using a LF (\n) only. Some poor quality Unix mail transfer agents replace LF by CRLF automatically (which leads to doubling CR if CRLF is used). This should be a last resort, as it does not comply with » RFC 2822.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try sending a simple mail without any meta, headers, mime etc first ! try out the php documentation examples first. I they dont work, you have a server problem (php module deactivated or something like that):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: '. $email. "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$email.'' . "\r\n" ;
```

In the above lines you have used $email, but it is not assigned. Have you assigned it somewhere else?

Comment: ok. Your code is correct. There may be a issue in your server

Answer (score 0):

1. It might not work on your local machine, because SMTP on your local machine might not be configured. Host this script on server where SMTP is properly configured.
2. Try change email address on which you are trying to send email. Sometimes it happens that php mail function does not send email to all domains. I recommend to try this code for gmail.com domain..

Comment: 1. I m testing in online... 2. i tried gmail and hotmail.. nth